# Mute the system when suspending in 14.04

Tags: sound, suspend

I am wondering if there is a way to mute the system as it goes to suspend in ubuntu 14.04.

I tried to add the following script called "90mute" to "/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d" (granting it +x rights)

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
   hibernate|suspend)
   amixer -D pulse sset Master mute
   ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Testing

```
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90mute suspend
```

gives the expected result.

Yet, when going to sleep the script does not seem to be executed (at least the system does not mute). Any clue someone?